# Setup a notebook with tabs and multiple gtk input fields on each tab using glade

Tags: gtk3, glade

I am an experienced Fortran programmer and have used an in-house UI package for many years with similar concepts to that of glade (3.22). I'm completely new to glade so I must be doing something bad due to a lack of understanding. My glade setup only uses gtkWindow and a gtkNotebook with some child tabs. All I want to do is add multiple fields (boxes and labels mostly) to a tab which covers the complete window area. Then when I switch tabs, I need to see a completely different page with it's own fields, also using the complete window area. Adding just one gtkButton takes up the whole page for the current tab and I cannot add another gtkbutton to that page. How do I add another button to the same page? If this is a stupid question, are there any good videos that demonstrate how to do it please? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option Edit Page from General to edit each of the pages in the glade.

[image]

You can change this value, and edit pages one by one, like add some box/grid then add buttons/label.

For adding new pages, right-click on one page and select 'insert page after' or 'insert page before'

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a [GtkBox](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBox.html) or a [GtkGrid](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkGrid.html) to your notebook tab. And [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch30s02.html) you can read a bit on the difference between a box and a grid. There are of course a lot of other [containers](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html) you could use to pack your widgets (in your case a button) into. Gtk3 only allows one widget per notebook page, so you have to add a multi-child widget to pack multiple widgets per page.

Comment: Excellent start. Gtkgrid did it for me HOWEVER, I wonder if this is the best way for me. I need a multi child widget for sure but looking at the doco, it's not obvious which ones are multi child. But this has made me aware of something else. The in-house UI I'm used to does everything by Row,Col values where each Row/Col "box" is the width/height of a single character using some default font. So I created the grid using 100 x 20 (which emulates the GUI I'm trying to convert to Gtk+3) and that makes glade run quite slowly :( but it works :)

Comment: I'm starting to think the job I'm tackling is massive. I would like to upload some piccies so someone can see what I'm trying to do. I like the concept behind Gtk+3, especially the gtkbuilder because the in-house software I use has the same principle but uses an ASCII file which describes all the buttons, labels etc. and where to position them. The GUI is generated at run-time so the file can alter the menu without recompiling the main program. I was hoping to write some code that would translate my menu files into the XML ui files required  by Gtk+3. Can I discuss in more detail with someone?

Answer (score 0):

1. download the glade file from there: https://github.com/f4iteightiz/UWR_simulator
2. edit / look at (this is a notebook with several inputs / buttons all different in each tabs).
   you will find few answers to your needs

Comment: Thank you so far gtknerd for a more detailed dscussion on how I get into gtk+ for my particular purpose. Now I need to simply "get into it", no doubt with many more Q's later on :)